# C# Get process id from ExecutablePath

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a process id in C# from ExecutablePath.
When I enter wmiQueryString into WMI Tester, it works without a problem.
But if I enter it into the code, it throws me an invalid query error.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
 
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string wmiQueryString = "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ExecutablePath ='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ASUS\\AI Suite III\\AISuite3.exe'";
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
            {
                using (var results = searcher.Get())
                {
                    ManagementObject mo = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (mo != null)
                    {
                        int procId = 0;
 
                        int.TryParse(mo["ProcessId"].ToString(), out procId);
 
                        Console.WriteLine(procId);
 
                    }
                }
            }
 
           
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't like the backslashes.  You have to escape them twice, once for the compiler and again for the WMI query interpreter, so use 4 backslashes.

Comment: It helped but now I get an error "Object reference not set to an object instance." on "ManagementObject mo = results.Cast <ManagementObject> () .FirstOrDefault ();"

Answer (score 0):

The approach via the management objects looks rather complicated. Is there a special reason for this? Else you could just use .NETs standard Process class for obtaining a process ID.

```
Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in processCollection)
{
    fullPath = p.MainModule.FileName;
    if (fullPath == "c:\\abcd.exe")
    {
        return p.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is that I need to get the process id according to ExecutablePath and not ProcessName.

Comment: Edited it for the file name... than its the MainModule.FileName property instead of the Name property.

Comment: In this case, I get an Unable to enumerate the process modules error. I understand that this is a permission issue but I need to run the program without administrator privileges.